# Reproject vector layer in oracle or PostGIS without export!

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, oracle-spatial

I have some vector layers in Oracle and PostGIS, point, line and polygon, and i want to reproject those layer in a different projection but i don't want to export the projected layer, i want to do it on the original layer because i have related tables with the feature ID. I know about on the fly projection but i want to permanent transform the data.

Comment: What have you tried? What happens when you use `ST_TRANSFORM` in an update statement?

Answer (score 1):

In both databases you can't transform into the same column, if the column is registered. Both databases hold the projection srid inside the geometry.

If you insert a geometry with a different projection, maybe you break a constraint or maybe the spatial index rebuild failed.

Best way is write the transformation result into a new table or column.
Check the result. Delete the spatial index, De-register the original column. Update the new geometries to the original column. Register the column and create a new spatial index.

Comment: Have you tried this before and in which database type?

Comment: I wrote years ago an import/export service for Oracle, who used a staging table with two geometry columns, for auto correction of the incoming geometries. That's equivalent to your use case.

My experience with postgis, say it's the same her.